# How do I alter specific values in an array then convert the array to a string in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have explained what I want it to do down below. I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out and I would really appreciate some help.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Input a palindrome");

      String str = s.nextLine();

      String strL = str.toLowerCase();

      String[] strSplit = strL.split("");

      // After this I need to alter the array and make all 4's become a's, all 3's become e's, and all 0's become o's. then I need to make that a string named "strSplitRev". I have no idea how to do that.



    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your "explanation" to the question itself?  The comment runs well past the right margin and is hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is loop through your array `strSplit` using a `for loop` which would look something like this

`for(int i = 0; i< strSpil.length; i++)`

inside your for loop you would check if `strSplit[i]` equals 4,3 etc and replace it with a,e etc. For example

```
if (strSplit[i].equals("4"){
 strSplit[i] = "a"
}
```

this or you could use switch/case statements. And in the same loop you can append all the individual characters to a `StringBuilder` object

Answer (score 0):

Hope it'll be helpful. Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

```
String strSplitRev="";
      for(int i=0;i<strSplit.length;i++){
          System.out.println(strSplit[i]);
          if(Integer.parseInt(strSplit[i])==0){
            strSplitRev+="o";  
          }
          else if(Integer.parseInt(strSplit[i])== 3){
                strSplitRev+="e";  
              }
          else if(Integer.parseInt(strSplit[i])==4){
                strSplitRev+="a";  
              }
          else strSplitRev+=strSplit[i];
      }
```